# VB.NET - Randomize() with a function call in a string.replace method

Tags: vb.net, string, random, replace

I have a chat system and i want to put a "random string generator".

In my chat i have to write "%random%" and it is replaces with a random string.

I have a problem though, if i type "%random%%random%%random%" for example, it will generate the same string 3 times.

• Here is my function:

```
Public Function getRandomString(ByVal len As Integer) As String
    Randomize()

    Dim stringMap as string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwvxyz0123456789"
    Dim rndString As String = ""
    Dim rnd As New Random()

    For i As Integer = 0 To len - 1
        Randomize()
        rndString &= stringMap.Substring(rnd.Next(0, stringMap.Length), 1)
    Next

    Return rndString
End Function
```

• And here is my function call:

```
    Dim msg As String = "Random string: %random%%random%%random%"
    msg = msg.Replace("%random%", getRandomString(8))
    MsgBox(msg)
```

The output for example: Random string: 5z15if725z15if725z15if72

I guess this is because it keeps the 1st return value in memory and pastes it, how can i fix that ?

Do i have to make a string.replace function myself ? Thanks

Comment: Old story, never call Randomize inside a loop. See this C# but it is the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to create your own replace. You can take a look at [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(v=vs.110).aspx) it might offer what you want.

Comment: Steve: Thanks for the tip, i tried to remove/move the randomize() calls plus doing it with the "Lock" method but i can't create curly brackets blocks like c#

the_lotus: Do you really think so ? That's problematic

Answer (score 1):

Oh no! You shouldn't call [`Randomize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) here at all! Random is used in combination with the [`Rnd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx) function of VB. Creating a new Random object is enough here.
The reason you are getting the same results every time is because you are creating a new Random every time. You should reuse the same object to get different results.

```
'Create the object once
Private Shared rnd As New Random()

Public Function getRandomString(ByVal len As Integer) As String
    Dim stringMap as string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwvxyz0123456789"
    Dim rndString As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To len - 1
        rndString &= stringMap.Substring(rnd.Next(0, stringMap.Length), 1)
    Next

    Return rndString
End Function
```

**EDIT:** I realize that in addition to the above changes, you need to call the getRandomString function for every `"%random%"`. `String.Replace` only calls the function once and pastes the result everywhere. With Regex, you could do something like this:

```
msg = new Regex("%random%").Replace(input, Function (match) getRandomString(8))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i tried this, but it's not working, same results, help appreciated though

Comment: Still the same results..
Damn you clock :p

Is it impossible to randomize() somewhere to change the seed ?

Comment: Updated my answer, the issue was unrelated to my latest fix.

Comment: I think i got it, it's what i had in mind, but there's an exception, if i write:
    msg = New Regex("%random%").Replace(msg, Function(match) return getRandomString(8))
It's throwing an exception and telling that the replace method can't be called with these arguments (kinda hard to translate it    from fr to en) 
if i write this instead
    msg = New Regex("%random%").Replace(msg, getRandomString(8))
same string appear 3 times, like the string.replace method.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is to find the first occurrence of "%random%", replace that, then repeat as necessary.

Written as a console application:

```
Option Infer On

Module Module1

    Dim rand As New Random

    Public Function getRandomString(ByVal len As Integer) As String

        Dim stringMap As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwvxyz0123456789"
        Dim rndString As String = ""

        For i As Integer = 0 To len - 1
            rndString &= stringMap.Substring(rand.Next(0, stringMap.Length), 1)
        Next

        Return rndString

    End Function

    Function ReplaceRandoms(s As String) As String
        Dim stringToReplace = "%random%"
        Dim r = s.IndexOf(stringToReplace)
        While r >= 0
            s = s.Remove(r, stringToReplace.Length).Insert(r, getRandomString(stringToReplace.Length))
            r = s.IndexOf(stringToReplace)
        End While

        Return s

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim msg As String = "Random string: %random%%random%%random%"
        msg = ReplaceRandoms(msg)
        Console.WriteLine(msg)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```